# Picker not selectable when selecting custom objects in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

In the following code, I have two Picker Views, the first one is grabbing its components from an array of 'Strings' and the second one grabs its components from an array of custom objects. The first Picker works as expected, you can select other dogs, but in the second one, you cannot select other objects.

How can I make the second Picker View select other objects? What am I missing?

```
class Dog:NSObject {
    var name = ""
    
    init(name: String = "") {
        self.name = name
    }
}

struct TestingGeneral: View {
    @State private var selectedDog = ""
    let dogs = ["Luna", "Max", "Cooper"]
    
    let dogs2 = [Dog(name:"Pluto"), Dog(name: "Teddy"), Dog(name: "Rocky")]
    
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Picker("Dogs 1:", selection: $selectedDog) {
                ForEach(dogs, id: \.self) { dog in
                    Text(dog)
                }
            }
            
            Picker("Dogs 2:", selection: $selectedDog) {
                ForEach(dogs2, id: \.self) { dog in
                    Text(dog.name)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Types you have [String] and [Dog] for “tag” trying to become String for the selection. You have to find a way for the “tag” type to be the exact same as the selection type for all the possible options

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/picker

Comment: Changing 'ForEach(dogs2, id: \.self) { dog in
                    Text(dog.name)
                }'  to                                'ForEach(dogs2, id: \.self) {
                    Text($0.name).tag($0.name)
                }' did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution. Thank you `lorem ipsum` for pointing me in the right direction.

```
class Dog:NSObject {
    var name = ""
    
    init(name: String = "") {
        self.name = name
    }
}

struct TestingGeneral: View {
    @State private var selectedDog = ""    
    let dogs2 = [Dog(name:"Pluto"), Dog(name: "Teddy"), Dog(name: "Rocky")]
    
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Picker("Dogs 2:", selection: $selectedDog) {
                ForEach(dogs2, id: \.self) {
                    Text($0.name).tag($0.name)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```